# what are the figurative meanings of "the light switch goes off"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, figurative

This is part of a CNN news article I need to translate. I am not quite sure about what situation the phrase describes. Here is the part the expression comes from: "When did **the light switch go off** for you to say, oh, my goodness, things have really drastically changed and I'm in trouble if I don't change with them?"

Comment: We need more context than that.

Comment: Without more context it's difficult to be sure but it looks to me as though the writer has had two idioms in mind and managed to conflate them. I think they might have been trying to choose between "the light (switch) go on" and "the alarm bell go off" both of which are metaphors for a sudden realisation or revalation. Then again I'm British and it might be an American idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading a [transcript of an interview](http://www.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1608/31/cnr.02.html), not an article, and as such the English may not be as polished as a written and edited article. 
[Cristina Alesci](http://www.cnn.com/profiles/cristina-alesci-profile) (the interviewer) is referring to a [*light bulb moment*](http://andtodaysidiomis.blogspot.ca/2010/11/light-bulb-moment.html), in which an idea or realization is formed, represented in cartoons by a light bulb over the person's head being switched on.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer!! It is very helpful. But I still wonder why she said "off" instead of "on".

Comment: As the comment above from@BoldBen, she is conflating something 'going off' (as an alarm) with something being 'switched on' (as a light switch). It's not perfect, but her meaning is clear enough.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany don't we all do that from time to time? I know I do!